# How to substract from the resut of two selects in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to substract two numbers, one is the contents of a field, the other is the sum of a query result, how can I do it? this shows what I want, but obviously does not work, how to do it?

```
SELECT monto FROM programaPago WHERE id=2
 **MINUS**
SELECT SUM( caja.monto ) FROM caja  WHERE caja.programaPago_id =2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT ( programaPago.monto - COALESCE(iTotal.TotalMonto,0)) Result
FROM programaPago LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT programaPago_id, SUM(monto) as TotalMonto
    FROM caja GROUP BY programaPago_id) as iTotal
        ON programaPago.ID = iTotal.programaPago_id
WHERE programaPago.ID = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
SELECT
    (SELECT monto FROM programaPago WHERE id = 2) - 
    (SELECT SUM(caja.monto) FROM caja WHERE caja.programaPago_id = 2)
```

But not knowing what you are trying to achieve there can be a better way of doing this